# How to get sine term in Analytical continuation of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I am able to prove the symmetric functional equation that Riemann gives in his paper, using Poisson Summation and properties of $\theta(x)$.

The functional equation is given like so,

\begin{equation}
\pi^{-\frac{s}{2}} \Gamma(\frac{s}{2})\zeta(s) = \pi^{-\frac{1-s}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{1-s}{2}) \zeta(1-s)
\end{equation}

Now to get $\zeta(s)$ on its own do I just divide the right hand side by $\pi^{-\frac{s}{2}} \Gamma(\frac{s}{2})$? How do I manipulate that expression to use the result from the product formula for sine? Or better still is there a more efficient way to show the trivial zeroes at the negative even integers?

Comment: "... at the even negative integers"; If you divide through to get $$\zeta(s) = \pi^{s-1/2}\frac{\Gamma\bigl(\frac{1-s}{2}\bigr)}{\Gamma\bigl(\frac{s}{2}\bigr)}\zeta(1-s),$$ you're pretty much there, for you know that $\Gamma$ has simple poles at the non-positive integers, so $1/\Gamma$ has simple zeros there. Only the zero at $s = 0$ is cancelled by the pole of $\zeta$ at $1$, the zeros of $1/\Gamma(s/2)$ at $s =  -2, -4, -6, \dotsc$ remain.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks I had just spotted that and edited it.

Comment: @DanielFischer so it is not necessary to use the sine product representation? this suffices? Now to look at odd negative integers, would I be advised to study Bernoulli numbers?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sine term you have to make some standard manipulations of the Gamma function. We have $$\zeta\left(s\right)=\pi^{s-1/2}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{s}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}\zeta\left(1-s\right)
 $$ then by the [duplication formula of Gamma and the Euler's reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Gamma_function), we get $$\zeta\left(s\right)=\pi^{s-1/2}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{s}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}\zeta\left(1-s\right)=\pi^{s}2^{s}\frac{\Gamma\left(1-s\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{s}{2}\right)}\zeta\left(1-s\right)=\pi^{s-1}2^{s}\sin\left(\pi s/2\right)\Gamma\left(1-s\right)\zeta\left(1-s\right). 
 $$